# Notepad++ Regex based on position of character

Tags: regex, notepad++

For Example lets say I have those Lines

```
Example123 23 456 45 - car - bus
Example34 2123 - school
Example67 today - truck - Train
```

I want to delete ONLY expressions which located before "first" (-).
How I can match the character position with Regex?

Comment: As a result from your example, what you want is `car - bus` and `school` and `truck - Train` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I aim for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will match everything before the first `-` on a line:

```
^.*?(?=-)
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/a7kxj7)

This works by matching the start of the line, then matching any character 0 or more times, until it sees a "-" character, but doesn't include that in the match since it's a look ahead `(?=-)`.

- Example123 23 456 45 - car - bus => - car - bus
- Example34 2123 - school => - school
- Example67 today - truck - Train => - truck - Train

If you don't want to include the dash and white space change it to:

```
^.*?-\s*
```

Also you might have to check `matches newline` as an option to work in Notepad++ so `^` matches start of a line.